# annotate is adding an extra object to my queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF. I've got the following code where I annotate a queryset of `Company` objects with an additional `joined` field. It seems `annotate` is adding an extra object to my queryset.

views.py

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        
        companies = Company.objects.all()

        print(companies)
        
        user_in_queue = When(queue__users=user, then = True)
        
        companies = Company.objects.annotate(joined=Case(
            user_in_queue, default = False
        ))
        
        print(companies)
```

models.py

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
class User(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.username}"


class Queue(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="queue"
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="QueueDetails", related_name="queues")

class QueueDetails(models.Model):
    
    queue = models.ForeignKey(
        Queue,
        related_name="queue_details",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name="queue_details",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

the first `print` gives me

```
<QuerySet [<Company: kfc>, <Company: kfc>]>
```

With a json of

```json
[
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 2,
    }
]
```

The second gives me

```
<QuerySet [<Company: kfc>, <Company: kfc>, <Company: kfc>]>
```

With a json of

```json
[
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 1,
        "joined": null
    },
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 1,
        "joined": true
    },
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 2,
        "joined": null
    }
]
```

I want
a json of

```json
[
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 1,
        "joined": true
    },
    {
        "name": "kfc",
        "id": 2,
        "joined": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Please share your `Queue` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added my models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to work with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) to prevent joining:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    companies = Company.objects.annotate(
        joined=Exists(
            Queue.objects.filter(company_id=OuterRef('pk'), users=request.user)
        )
    )
    # …
```

For the serializer, you add a `joined` field:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    joined = serializers.BooleanField()

    # …
```